# How do I add a theme font to a ribbon?

Tags: ribbon

I have Arial and Verdana as Theme Font. I want to add Tahoma to the Theme Fonts as well. How do I add a theme font to the ribbon?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to the styles for the page:

```
.ms-rteThemeFontFace-3
{
  -ms-name:"Tahoma";
  font-family:Tahoma;
}
```

Comment: How does this work? I assume sharepoint somehow parse styles and build the drop down with fonts using parsed styles and javascript? Am I correct?

Comment: @Kai Yes, you can see the implementation in 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\SP.UI.Rte.debug.js' if you want

Answer (score 2):

Refer this link : http://styledpoint.com/blog/ribbon-customization-changing-placement-look-and-behavior/

It may help... :)

Comment: It's considered good practice to summarise any links you answer with in case of link rot.

Comment: Also, that particular link doesn't even mention adding fonts to the Theme fonts section.